Remote Powershell exec from PHP (Exchange on-prem) : Access Denied
I have a powershell script creating user mailbox called by PHP running in a IIS 10 server.
The thing is, when I run this script from the Webserver in powershell it works but when I run it from PHP, I get Access Denied
Connecting to remote server server.domain.local failed with the following error message : Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic. At C:\Scripts\AD_CreateMailbox.ps1:46 char:34 + ... sessionEX = New-PSSession -sessionOption $sessionOption -Configuratio ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotin gTransportException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionOpenFailed

Things I did :

Enable Remote Powershell on exchange server
Allow the Webserver in the Trustedhosts of the Exchange's WinRM
Run the Webserver with a restricted domain User with the appropriate rights to create a Mailbox
Allow Kerberos auth on Exchange's server

I'm guessing maybe I have to use IIS impersonation but not really sure and I did not really find anything well detailed on how to configure this.
Do you have some tips on this or anybody have ever make this work perhaps ?
Thanks :)

Things running in your user session can simply break when switching to system session/IIS, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 Since PHP does not easily expose the impersonation to you and now even not remains supported by Microsoft, you are likely to hit more issues.

As Lex Li said, Microsoft no longer supports PHP on Windows/IIS, you can switch to Linux hosting.

Yes maybe, but this will unlikely solve my problem. PowerShell scripts to AD are working on the same server so my issue is specific to Exchange

Figured out after monitoring on both sides (Webserver and Exchange) after reading this post : https://codermike.blogspot.com/2016/06/new-pssession-access-denied.html
Turned out the issue came from the webserver and the IIS right to write in the registry.
The key which the IUSR needs to have write access on : HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WSMAN\Client\ConnectionCookies
Turn out this key was missing on my webserver so I created it and allowed the IUSR to write in it.
